# Unable to display text in Hindi ( utf-8 ) in R buffer in Emacs

Tags: r, emacs, xml-parsing

I am trying to read a Hindi word file (docx) from an R buffer from inside Emacs. The output is as follows:

```
> library(textreadr)
> read_document("example.docx")
[1] "à¤¦à¤¿à¤¨à¤¾à¤à¤: 25-07-2018" "à¤à¤ªà¤à¤¾ à¤¦à¤¿à¤¨ à¤¶à¥à¤­ à¤¹à¥"   
>
```

If I do the SAME thing in R studio or R running in a terminal I can parse it fine. I do not get gibberish.

[The docx file](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AktPVykOSvuZaSKo7n1xRjWAHcs)

Any help will be appreciated. The problem is specific to R buffer inside emacs.

Comment: Check the output of the command ` Sys.getlocale()`, and include it in your post.

Comment: Here is the output of `Sys.getlocale()`  

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_IN;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_IN;LC_COLLATE=en_IN;LC_MONETARY=en_IN;LC_MESSAGES=en_IN;LC_PAPER=en_IN;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"   

Here is our attempt to fix this:
> `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", locale="hi_IN")`
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", locale = "hi_IN") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "hi_IN" cannot be honored

Comment: Try `en_IN.UTF-8`. If it doesn't work in R, you may have to try and see how to change your system default.

Comment: We tried this option, `Sys.setlocale` is not giving warning anymore. But the output of  `read_document("example.docx")` is still this- 
[1] "à¤¦à¤¿à¤¨à¤¾à¤à¤: 25-07-2018" "à¤à¤ªà¤à¤¾ à¤¦à¤¿à¤¨ à¤¶à¥à¤­ à¤¹à¥".

Comment: Have you tried specifying `encoding="UTF-8"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.
The problem was solved by changing emacs environment to multilingual. This is done by F10->Options->Multilingual Environment->Set Coding Systems->For I/O with subprocesses. Shortcut is C-x RET p.
The coding systems for input and output are asked in minibuffer. In this case, they were both set to utf-8.
This was inspired by ( but not completely answered by ) the following discussion:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37459/how-encode-to-utf-8-content-of-buffer